# Spring Cloud Dataflow Sort Jpbs or Tasks according to the last failed

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

Is there a way that i can sort my jobs in the job execution page or my tasks also according to the ones which failed last?

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui#914](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/914).

It is a planned enhancement for the future releases.